# Kryonet connect udp: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: udp, client, port, server, kryonet

I am new to server development. I am trying out Kryonent. I made a server using

```
server.bind(8000,30003)//8000 as tcp port, 30003 as udp port
```

and a client using

```
client.connect(5000,"0.0.0.0",8000,30003);//5000 is timeout
```

I am testing both client and server on the same windows laptop using IP 0.0.0.0.
Exception occured:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to: /0.0.0.0:30003
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.UdpConnection.connect(UdpConnection.java:66)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:171)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:110)
at chen.yiou.kryonetApp.KRClient.initClient(KRClient.java:31)
at chen.yiou.kryonetApp.KRClient.<init>(KRClient.java:20)
at chen.yiou.kryonetApp.KRClient.main(KRClient.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:435)
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.connect(DatagramChannelImpl.java:738)
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.connectInternal(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:81)
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.connect(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:108)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.UdpConnection.connect(UdpConnection.java:56)
... 10 more
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same machine, just replace 0.0.0.0 with 127.0.0.1, which is the local loopback interface.